# Why can't I recover selected items from a React Dropdown Tree Select

Tags: reactjs, react-dropdown-tree-select

I'm having all kinds of trouble recovering values from a ReactDropdownTreeSelect. The component seems to keep it's state just fine, up until I want save the results of a change. However I try to do this, the component loses it's state and nothing is selected. What am i missing?

[This is a simplest](https://github.com/bbsimonbb/debug-selector/tree/main/src) example, [nearly identical to the one in the help](https://github.com/dowjones/react-dropdown-tree-select#usage), that shows the problem. One line breaks it...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import DropdownTreeSelect from "react-dropdown-tree-select"

function DebugSelector() {
    const [mySelected, setMySelected] = useState([]);
    const [lastChanged, setLastChanged] = useState({});

    const tarifs = {
        label: "all tarifs", value: "all", children: [
            { label: "second level tarif", value: "secondLevel" },
            { label: "another 2nd level", value: "secondLevel2" }
        ]
    }
    const onChange = function (currNode, selectedNodes) {
        debugger
        // Any of these lines will break it. The component loses its state.
        //setMySelected(selectedNodes);
        //setMySelected([...selectedNodes]);
        //setLastChanged(currNode);
        setLastChanged(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(currNode)))
    }
    return (
        <DropdownTreeSelect data={tarifs} onChange={onChange}></DropdownTreeSelect>
    )
}
export default DebugSelector;
```

Comment: were you able to figure out the way to solve the problem? I'm in a similar position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve its state, `react-dropdown-tree-select` needs to be wrapped in a class component that prevents re-renders if props have not changed. The class component can then proxy the onChange handler. This is my working wrapper...

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import DropdownTreeSelect from "react-dropdown-tree-select"
import isEqual from "lodash/isEqual"
import { TarifForTreeSelect } from "interfaces/TarifForTreeSelect"

interface IProps {
  data: TarifForTreeSelect
  onChange: (currentNode: any, selectedNodes: any) => void
  hasError?: any
  contentTitle?: string
  triggerTitle?: string
  isLoading?: boolean
}

interface IState {
  data: TarifForTreeSelect
}

class TarifsSelector extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { data: props.data }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps: IProps) => {
    if (!isEqual(nextProps.data, this.state.data)) {
      this.setState({ data: nextProps.data })
    }
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps: IProps) => {
    return !isEqual(nextProps.data, this.state.data)
  }

  render() {
    const onChangeTemp = (currentNode: any, selectedNodes: any) => {
      this.props.onChange(currentNode, selectedNodes)
    }

    return (
      <>
        <DropdownTreeSelect data={this.state.data && this.state.data.value !== "" ? this.state.data : []} onChange={onChangeTemp} showDropdown="always" />
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default React.memo(TarifsSelector)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `setLastChanged` is not defined so it will generate an error.

Also, if you call `setMySelected` the component will be re-rendered and based on the code, `DropdownTreeSelect` doesn't have a prop with the updated values, what I think you should do is to update `tarifs` when any change is done, so, something like:

```js
const [tarifs, setTarifs] = useState({
  label: foo, value: bar, children: [baz]
})

const onChange = function (currNode, selectedNodes) {
  setTarifs(currNode);
}

return <DropdownTreeSelect data={tarifs} onChange={onChange}/>;
```

Comment: Sorry to waste your time. I copied in that fourth line to the question without copying in the corresponding definition. That's not the problem. I've updated the question. Fork the github and you'll see the problem running.

Comment: Got it, probably creating a codepen to see it in action will be great, but I still think the issue is because of the re-rendering that happens when a state (in this case `mySelected` or `lastChanged`) is modified, maybe a quirk/quick workaround is to memoize `DropdownTreeSelect` and only refreshing it when `tarifs` is modified

Answer (score -2):

`

```
const onChange = (currentNode, selectedNodes) => {
   console.log("onChange::", currentNode);
   var category = [];
   dataRef.current.map((parent_item) => {
      category.push(get_nested_categories(parent_item, currentNode));
    });

   console.log("-----::", category);
    setData([...category]);
 };


function get_nested_categories(category, currentNode) {
   var nested_category = {
       label: category.label,
       id: category.id,
       children: [],
       checked: category?.checked
               ? true
               : category.id == currentNode.id
               ? true
               : false,
    };
    category.children.map((child) => {
           nested_category["children"].push(
           get_nested_categories(child, currentNode)
           );
     });
     return nested_category;
   }

  <DropdownTreeSelect
          data={dataRef.current}
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          onAction={onAction}
          onNodeToggle={onNodeToggle}
          keepTreeOnSearch={true}
          mode="hierarchical"
          keepOpenOnSelect={true}
          placeholderText="select category"
          inlineSearchInput={true}
        />
```

`